# Could not load settings in AuthorizeService in .net core 3 + angular application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I've been trying to set up a .net core 3 angular application with default identity authentication using the below command:

dotnet new angular -o  -au Individual

I was able to build and run the application succesfully but with set of error messages as below:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load settings for 'pos_app'
Error: Could not load settings for 'pos_app'
    at AuthorizeService. (authorize.service.ts:179)

when I go into the AuthorizeService to check the error, it breaks on the below line:

```
const response = await fetch(ApplicationPaths.ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl);
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error(`Could not load settings for '${ApplicationName}'`);
}
```

I also get some error messages as below:

GET http://localhost:50059/_configuration/pos_app 404 (Not Found)

And when I hit the default Register button, i get the below error message:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Identity/Account/Register'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Identity/Account/Register'

I wonder what Im missing, since I didnt change anything and the default application should work.
Please help.

I am using Mac if that makes a difference

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, I simply created a new application and the error went away. Not sure what was causing the issue @anatol

Answer (score 2):

Well. Let recheck your controller. There is a controller named OidcConfigurationController. That serves to return the configuration for front end. I got this error once i tried to refactor my code and delete that controller. 
You can create new angular project with identity to get that controller code and add to your current project

```
public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> logger;

    public OidcConfigurationController(IClientRequestParametersProvider clientRequestParametersProvider, ILogger<OidcConfigurationController> _logger)
    {
        ClientRequestParametersProvider = clientRequestParametersProvider;
        logger = _logger;
    }

    public IClientRequestParametersProvider ClientRequestParametersProvider { get; }

    [HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
    public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
    {
        var parameters = ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, clientId);
        return Ok(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that [HttpGet("_configuration/{client-id}] maps to server root, for example https://server.com/_configuration/myapp. 
But, my app is hosted at https://server.com/myapp, so correct url should be https://server.com/myapp/_configuration/_myapp. 
All other controllers map correctly, except OidcConfigurationController

Comment: @mariob that depends on how you config your route and IIS. Double check your IIS config root URL and route

Comment: My problem was on client side, api-authorization.constants.ts had   ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl: `/_configuration/${ApplicationName}`,

I just removed / at the beginning and it is working now.

Comment: @mariob -- On my desktop, I had that first forward-slash, and it never caused a problem. Yet when pulling my code down onto my laptop, I received this problem which was fixed by your solution in your comment. I also noticed that new VS2019 scaffolding for a new Angular project generates the ApiAUthorizationClientConfigurationUrl constant without the leading forward-slash. Did you find anything else out about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, I am new to angular so I didn't realise this immidietly.
But I had the exact same issue, the issue lies in that if you start your application with the command:

> ng-serve

The backend doesn't start, just start the backend normaly and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurred for me when added a filter for controllers in a blazor hosted project, specifically on Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(Shared.Policies.MyPolicy()));
            });
```

The accepted answer inspired me to fix by adding [AllowAnonymous] at OidcConfigurationController

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
```